# фильтрация повторяющихся словарных конструкций

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, фильтр

Задача такая: существует постоянный обмен письмами в шапке письма встречаются такие слова как "Срочно" "Очень Срочно", при попытке вытащить из шапки это слово что бы создать файл возникает повторение, а конкретно мой цикл реагирует в случае "Сверх Срочно" на обе конструкции и выводит в файле с метаданными письма и один и второй результат

*цикл поиска*

```
name: str = input ("Введите имя входящего файла: ")
f = open (name, "r")  # открываем файл
lines = f.readlines ()  # читаем его построчно    
for line in lines:
        if line.find ('Срочно') != -1:  # то что ищем
            t9 = line [7:40]  # определяет глубину
            print (t9)  # выводим на экран проверяем
            break
# --------
for line in lines:
    if line.find ('Сверх Срочно') != -1:  # то что ищем
        t10 = line [7:40]  # определяет глубину
        print (t10)  # выводим на экран проверяем
        break
```

*вывод в файл*

```
name1: str = input ("Введите имя исходящего файла: ")
f = open (name1, "w+")  
  if 't9' in globals ():  # 't9' in locals()
        f.write ('\n//Пометка принадлежности// ' + 'Срочно')
    if 't10' in globals ():  # 't10' in locals()
        f.write ('\n//Пометка принадлежности// ' + 'Сверх срочно')
f.close ()
```

**Исходя из этой проблемы и появляется вопрос, как правильно искать такие словарные конструкции с повторяющимся "корнем"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала проверьте более специфичный случай, а потом менее специфичный, используя конструкцию `if/elif`:

```
    if 't10' in globals ():  # 't10' in locals()
        f.write ('\n//Пометка принадлежности// ' + 'Сверх срочно')
    elif 't9' in globals ():  # 't9' in locals()
        f.write ('\n//Пометка принадлежности// ' + 'Срочно')
```

Второй `if` проверится только в том случае, если не сработает первый.
Сам поиск можно тоже сделать аналогичным образом, два цикла там не нужны, можно сделать обе проверки в одном цикле аналогично тому коду, который я выше привёл.

Comment: Понято, принято)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы ушел от конструкции `if/else` к использованию списка с ключами `"Срочно"`, `"Сверх срочно"` или, если нужно как-то потом обрабатывать, словарю с ключем в виде типа срочности и значением к нему в виде функции обработки. Потом список сортируем по убыванию длинным строки. И ищем включения в итерируемые строки текста.

В принципе все можно в один блок загнать, чем разделять на два кода. Открываем два файла. Один читаем, второй пишем. Итерируем текст строку за строкой, ищем в ней ключевые слова.

```
funcs = ['Срочно', 'Сверх срочно', ]

name_r = 'file_1.txt'
name_w = 'file_2.txt'

with open(name_r, "r") as file_1, open(name_w, "w+") as file_2:
    for line in file_1:
        for f in sorted(funcs, key=len, reverse=True):  # Сортируем в виде ['Сверх срочно', 'Срочно', ]
            if f in line:
                text = line[7:40]  # определяет глубину
                print(text)  # выводим на экран проверяем
                file_2.write (f'\n//Пометка принадлежности// {f}')
```

Comment: способ интересный, но с ним придётся переписывать кучу всего

Comment: Ну так не последний код пишите)